# How to save record from a different object using nested recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform, nested

I have managed to get fields from two different objects to display in one lighting component but I am having a few problems off the back of this.

When saving it will only save the main record and wont create a new record for the Budget Planner object. Also when using the two Name fields it saves the input from the Budget Planner Name in the Factfind record even when i define a factfind name in the field.

Here is my cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" 
            access="global">

<aura:attribute name="selTabId" type="string" default="Objective" />

<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>


<!--Style-->
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container{
    height : auto;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 70rem;
    }
    .modal-body{
    height : 750px !important;
    max-height: 750px !important;
    }

    .customFooter{
    display: inline !important;
    }
</aura:html> 

<!--Content-->

<aura:if isTrue="{!!v.saved}">
    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Factfind__c"

                              onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                              onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:tabset selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}" variant="vertical" class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_x-small">
            <lightning:tab label="Objectives" id="Objective">

                <h2>TFC Section</h2>
                <p>This is the record id {!v.recordId}</p>

                <div style="width: 50%; padding: 14px;" class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-around_medium">                

                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}"/> 
                    <p/><br/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
                    <p/><br/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="WantsImmediateTFC__c"/>
                    <p/><br/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="RequiredTFCAmount__c"/>
                </div>

                <p/><br/>

                <table style="width: 100%">

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X1_Why_Do_You_Require_TFC__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X1TFCAmountNeeded__c"/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X2WhyDoYouRequireTFC__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X2TFCAmountNeeded__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X3WhyDoYouRequireTFC__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X3TFCAmountNeeded__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X4WhyDoTheyRequireTFC__c"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="X4TFCAmountNeeded__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div style="float: right; width: 50%; padding: 14px">

                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalTFCBeingUsedForReasons__c"/>

                </div>


            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Occupation/Income" id="OccuIncome">

                <div>
                    NAHHHHHHHHH
                </div>



            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Assets and Debt" id="AssDebt">
                Im WITH MY 
            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Budget Planner" id="BudgetPlan">
                <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Budget_Planner__c"

                                          onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                                          onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
                    <lightning:messages />
                    <div>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
                        <p/><br/>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="MainEmploymentNetMonthlyIncome__c"/>
                        <p/><br/>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}"/>
                        <p/><br/>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalAmountOfStateBenefits__c"/>
                    </div>

                </lightning:recordEditForm>

            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Retirement Plans" id="RetirePlan">

            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Tick List" id="TickList">

            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="ATR" id="Atr">

            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Switch Questions" id="SwitchQs">
                Switch questions
            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Annuity Basis" id="AnnBas">
                Annuity Basis
            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="House Keeping" id="HouseKeep">
                House Keeping
            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Fact Find Complete" id="Complete">
                Fact Find has been completed!
            </lightning:tab>

        </lightning:tabset>      


        <!--Footer-->
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <div class="slds-docked-form-footer slds-modal__footer customFooter" style="height:55px;">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.closeQuickAction}"/> 
                    <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" type="submit" label="Save" variant="brand" name="save"/>
                </div> 
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <lightning:button disabled="{!v.selTabId == 'Objective'}" variant="neutral" label="Back" onclick="{!c.back}"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Next" onclick="{!c.next}"/>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <p>Saved! New record id is {!v.recordId}</p>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>


</aura:component>
```

and here is my controller:

```
({
closeQuickAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Close the action panel
    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
    dismissActionPanel.fire();
},

handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("this is a test");
    //Display toast message
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Success!",
        "message": "Factfind has been created.",
        "type": "success"
    });
    toastEvent.fire();


},

handleSuccess: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var params = event.getParams();
    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
    dismissActionPanel.fire();
    cmp.find("navService").navigate({
        "type": "standard__recordPage",
        "attributes": {
            "recordId": params.response.id,
            "objectApiName": "Factfind__c",
            "actionName": "view"
        }
    });
},

next : function(component, event, helper) {
    // get the current selected tab value
    var currentTab = component.get("v.selTabId");


    if(currentTab == 'Objective'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'OccuIncome');                              
    }else if(currentTab == 'OccuIncome'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AssDebt');                
    }else if(currentTab == 'AssDebt'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'BudgetPlan');  
    } else if(currentTab == 'BudgetPlan'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'RetirePlan');  
    } else if(currentTab == 'RetirePlan'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'TickList');  
    } else if(currentTab == 'TickList'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Atr');  
    } else if(currentTab == 'Atr'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'SwitchQs');  
    } else if(currentTab == 'SwitchQs'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AnnBas');  
    } else if(currentTab == 'AnnBas'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'HouseKeep');  
    } else if(currentTab == 'HouseKeep'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Complete');  
    } 

},

back : function(component, event, helper) {
    // get the current selected tab value  
    var currentTab = component.get("v.selTabId");

    if(currentTab == 'OccuIncome'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Objective');         
    } else if(currentTab == 'AssDebt'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'OccuIncome');     
    }else if(currentTab == 'BudgetPlan'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AssDebt');     
    } else if(currentTab == 'RetirePlan'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'BudgetPlan');     
    } else if(currentTab == 'TickList'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'RetirePlan');     
    } else if(currentTab == 'Atr'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'TickList');     
    } else if(currentTab == 'SwitchQs'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Atr');     
    } else if(currentTab == 'AnnBas'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'SwitchQs');     
    } else if(currentTab == 'HouseKeep'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AnnBas');     
    } else if(currentTab == 'Complete'){
        component.set("v.selTabId" , 'HouseKeep');     
    } 
}


})
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated :)

**update**

This is my new controller in which i am getting this error **Uncaught Action failed: c:JackBPTest$controller$mainSave [Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]**

```
        handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("this is a test");
        //Display toast message
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Success!",
            "message": "Factfind has been created.",
            "type": "success"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();


    },

    handleSuccessForBP : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log('Both Records Saved')
    },

    handleSuccessForObj : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        component.find("budgetPlanner").submit();
    },


    mainSave : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.find("Objective").submit();
        var params = event.getParams();
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        cmp.find("navService").navigate({
            "type": "standard__recordPage",
            "attributes": {
                "recordId": params.response.id,
                "objectApiName": "Factfind__c",
                "actionName": "view"
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of playing around off the back of @pranay's answer I have managed to get two records saving to two different objects.

The way I managed this was to save my secondary objects record during the `onsuccess` of the primary `recordEditForm`.

Here is my component :

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,lightning:actionOverride" 
                access="global">

    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>

        <lightning:tabset selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}" variant="vertical" class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_x-small">
            <lightning:tab label="Objectives" id="Objective">
                <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Factfind__c" aura:id="firstPage"
                                          onsubmit="{!c.submitFP}"
                                          onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">



                    </table>
                </lightning:recordEditForm>

            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab label="Budget Planner" id="BudgetPlan">
                <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Budget_Planner__c" aura:id="budgetPlanner">
                </lightning:recordEditForm>

            </lightning:tab>


        </lightning:tabset>      

        <!--Footer-->
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <div class="slds-docked-form-footer slds-modal__footer customFooter" style="height:55px;">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.closeQuickAction}"/> 
                    <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" onclick="{!c.submitFP}" label="Save" variant="brand" name="save"/>
                </div> 

</aura:component>
```

and here is my controller:

```
({
    closeQuickAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        // Close the action panel
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
    },



    submitFP : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("firstPage").submit();
        //Display toast message
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Success!",
            "message": "Factfind has been created.",
            "type": "success"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();


    },

    handleSuccess: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.find("budgetPlanner").submit();
        var params = event.getParams();
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        cmp.find("navService").navigate({
            "type": "standard__recordPage",
            "attributes": {
                "recordId": params.response.id,
                "objectApiName": "Factfind__c",
                "actionName": "view"
            }
        });
    },


    next : function(component, event, helper) {
        // get the current selected tab value
        var currentTab = component.get("v.selTabId");


        if(currentTab == 'Objective'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'OccuIncome');                              
        }else if(currentTab == 'OccuIncome'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AssDebt');                
        }else if(currentTab == 'AssDebt'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'BudgetPlan');  
        } else if(currentTab == 'BudgetPlan'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'RetirePlan');  
        } else if(currentTab == 'RetirePlan'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'TickList');  
        } else if(currentTab == 'TickList'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Atr');  
        } else if(currentTab == 'Atr'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'SwitchQs');  
        } else if(currentTab == 'SwitchQs'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AnnBas');  
        } else if(currentTab == 'AnnBas'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'HouseKeep');  
        } else if(currentTab == 'HouseKeep'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Complete');  
        } 

    },

    back : function(component, event, helper) {
        // get the current selected tab value  
        var currentTab = component.get("v.selTabId");

        if(currentTab == 'OccuIncome'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Objective');         
        } else if(currentTab == 'AssDebt'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'OccuIncome');     
        }else if(currentTab == 'BudgetPlan'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AssDebt');     
        } else if(currentTab == 'RetirePlan'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'BudgetPlan');     
        } else if(currentTab == 'TickList'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'RetirePlan');     
        } else if(currentTab == 'Atr'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'TickList');     
        } else if(currentTab == 'SwitchQs'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'Atr');     
        } else if(currentTab == 'AnnBas'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'SwitchQs');     
        } else if(currentTab == 'HouseKeep'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'AnnBas');     
        } else if(currentTab == 'Complete'){
            component.set("v.selTabId" , 'HouseKeep');     
        } 
    }


})
```

As you can see in my `handleSuccess` the first line submits the budget planner record then it redirects to the created factfind record just after.

In doing this I had to have a main `submitFP` which is what my button does `onclick` and this submits the whole factfind in order for the handleSuccess to run after this :)

Hope this makes sense for anyone else having issues with this.

Comment: Can you remove the unrelevant content and try to make it generic so that it can be used by someone else with similar issue?

Comment: I have removed all irrelevant content I can see anymore you think I should remove please let me know

Answer (score 1):

The save button exists only on outer `lightning:recordEditForm`, thus pressing save will only save the outer record.

Also, as its nested, the Markup gets confused for which Object's Name you are referring. It picks up last occurrence of Name and sets it for the Outer forms's submit.

Instead of nesting `lightning:recordEditForm` inside `lightning:recordEditForm` , have a common parent and put these 2 as siblings. You are using tabs, you can use them.

**Markup :**

```
<lightning:tabset>
        <lightning:tab label="FactFindForm">
            <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Factfind__c" aura:id="factFinder"
                              onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccessForFactfind}">

            //Fields here
            </Lightning:recordEditForm>
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Budget Planner" title="Budgett Planner">
            <light<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Budget_Planner__c" aura:id="budgetPlanner"
                                          onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccessForBudgetPlanner}">

            //Fields here
            </Lightning:recordEditForm>
        </lightning:tab>

</lightning:tabset>

<lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" onclick="{!c.mainSave}" label="Save" variant="brand" name="save"/>
```

**Javascript :**

```
mainSave(component , event , helper){
    component.find("factFinder").submit();

}

handleSuccessForFactfind(component , event , helper){
    component.find("budgetPlanner").submit();
}


handleSuccessForBudgetPlanner(component , event , helper){
    console.log('Both Records saved');
}
```

Comment: This seems to only save the later edit form every time?

Comment: Do i need the saveBothRecord to be on the handleSuccess instead?

Comment: handleSuccess is called after saving records, its just basic callback.
You can do something like save 1st record, and its `handleSuccess ` callback method save second record.

Comment: So I have adapted my code so both `recordEditForms` are inside tabs but when having just the `handleSuccess ` and linking it all the with the `saveBothRecord` you suggested it will only ever save one record

Comment: @JackDower updated code for the same.

Comment: I get an error saying mainSave component is not defined when trying to save, do i add my redirect into the mainSave in the controller now then as thats the last one to trigger?

Comment: Can you cross check `mainSave` exits in JS and markup?

Comment: Do i need to make `mainSave` an attribute in the markup aswell or just put it in the onlick on the button?

Comment: I am now getting a new error **Uncaught Action failed: c:JackBPTest$controller$mainSave [Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]** i will edit my question with my updated controller

Comment: Can you see if proper id are provided and every id is in double quotes? ""

Comment: all ids are correct and in the double quotes, its not even saving any record anymore

Comment: Hi @praynay i have managed to work this out myself thanks to your guidance, would you mind upvoting my answer so it gets seen :)